# Regex / mod-rewrite - picking up forward slashes

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have the following regex in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^suppliers/category/([\w\s-\/]*)$ /index.cfm?ct=suppliers.home/category/$1 [nc]
```

For some reason this code is not picking up the forward slash properly. e.g.

for the following url http://mydomainname.co.uk/suppliers/category/Archive/records%20Management I would expect the variable to be 'Archive/records Management' but instead it's just 'Archive'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any other rule that could get in conflict with this one?

Comment: I don't think so. When I remove this line I get a page not found error

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is working fine for me, in an isolated environment. My guess is that you've got other `RewriteRule`s which are conflicting with this rule.